# Facebook payment, API Error Code: 1383008

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-canvas, facebook-unity-sdk

I am getting API Error Code: 1383008 ,when i try to open Facebook pay dialog in canvas app,
I checked my callback URL is working in testing,
What should i do to fix it?

[Error screenshot](https://fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/t1.0-9/10363563_10203780050971506_296589272459583100_n.jpg)

Comment: Did you try waiting? might be a temporary error in Facebook's servers

Comment: after 1 day now i am getting this error  

**An error occurred. Please try again later.
API Error Code: 1383049
API Error Description: The entity backed by id 247978152056049 cannot be seen by the viewer with (userID 0, AccountID 0): DENY_RULE:EntApplicationPrivacyPolicy:DenyIfInDevModeRule:20 (EntID: 247978152056049)**

Comment: Have you tried running the url of the object you are trying to purchase by the open graph debugger tool? might see the error clearer there...https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: I uploaded my game to dropbox is this a reason for not responding?

Comment: Worked for me before. Have you tried what I suggested above?

Comment: yes i debug my URL its working perfect..
and i waited 1 day but this error still appearing 
API Error Code: 1383008

Comment: @gastonclaret my php and html of coin package are in http. but game file in https.
is there an error for http?

Comment: If there is an error with that, you can check in the console of the browser (check both in chrome & ff, sometimes in one of them doesn't show)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in your callback you just copied the sample for RTU implementation instead of the payments callback implementation;  You need to return the price for the item that you're trying to sell. There are two solutions to this:  either set the price in the OG object by adding this meta tags

```
<meta property="product:price:amount" content="0.10"/> 
<meta property="product:price:currency" content="USD"/>
```

or responding to the callback correctly:

```
<?php

try {
  if (isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['method'] && $_POST['method'] == "payments_get_item_price")) {


    $response = new StdClass();
    $response->content = new StdClass();
    $response->content->product = 'onetentechnology.com/devovertesting/coin.html';
    $response->content->amount = 1.0; //price
    $response->content->currency = $_POST['user_currency']; 
    $response->method = "payments_get_item_price"; 

    echo(json_encode($response));
  }
}
catch($error){
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you share with me the url of the item you're trying to sell? This error means that your server callback is not responding correctly to the request to get the item price. I can help you if you share more details!

You can also read more about dynamically priced items in this link:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/payments/definingproducts/#pricing_dynamic

Comment: Hi @Marco,

this is my OG product URL,___
http://onetentechnology.com/devovertesting/coin.html  and this the callback PHP code i used,___
https://github.com/Anglinadev/php/blob/master/callback  
____
both are working successful in debug tool and payment test, but not responding in actual game ,

Answer (score 0):

To fix issues with the Facebook Open Graph, use the [Facebook Open Graph Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/). You will find useful information on how to fix the issues.

Check the scraped output to find what have gone wrong.